# Retrieving data from Firebase returns null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the stored a User at the Firebase's database. When I want to retrieve the user it is null and I can't explain myself why. My User class simply consists of an `String` 'email' and `String` 'name' and `boolean` 'firstAppUse'.

[image]

So I wrote the following method to retrieve a user from database:

```
public static User getUser(){
    final User [] user = new User[1];
    DatabaseHelper.userDB.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            user[0] = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return user[0];
}
```

Narrow all expectations `user[0]` is null. Although the element exists in the database and the reference to it in `DatabaseHelper.userDB` is just fine:

```
public class DatabaseHelper {
private static FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
public static DatabaseReference userDB = database.getReference("users/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
```

}
Does anybody see the issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you try to create a Log in there to see if dataSnapshot.exists() return true?

Comment: user[0] will always be null because firebase database is async

Comment: @Salman500 could you explain it a bit more?

Comment: When you execute something asynchronously, you can move on to another task before it finishes

Answer (score 1):

Firebase database is async,

When the code gets into the 'return' line, the block of code in the 'onDataChange' callback didn't executed

[Please, read that article to learn more about async and sync methods](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93)

Answer (score 1):

user[0] will always be null because firebase database is asynchronous

```
// in userdb it should be like this
// database.child("users").child("uid")
private User mUser = null;
public void getUser(){

    DatabaseHelper.userDB.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              if dataSnapshot.exists(){
                 mUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
           // do something with user
                      }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch data from firebase, it is an **Asynchronous Task**. If you call getUser() and return user[0] then it will always return null because before getting results (`DataSnapshot`) from firebase you have returned the function.

Here is the code,

```
public static void getUser(Handler.Callback callback){
    DatabaseHelper.userDB.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            User userObj = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);;

            Message message = new Message();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("user",userObj); //Make sure that user object is serialisable
            message.setData(bundle);
            callback(message);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Message message = new Message();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("user",null);
            message.setData(bundle);
            callback(message);
        }
    });

}
```

Here is how you should call this function:

```
getUser(new Handler.Callback(){
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message message) {
            if(message != null){
               User user = (User)message.getData().get("user");
               //Do whatever you want with "user" object
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This will make your code modular. You can call this function anywhere in your code to get user object and you can keep all your firebase database listener code in a single place for separation of database layer and logic layer.

Comment: This answer is totally wrong. Because the ValueEventListener callback is already in the MainThread. There is no need to create handlers, messages, etc.

Comment: @YayoArellano true. If you want to use a continuous listener then it should be on the main thread but for single time query I believe we can separate the calls using this method.

Comment: @YayoArellano If you can provide a better way to separate my single value queries from the activity code then it would be of a great help.

Comment: More simple way is to create an interface, no need to user handlers. Take a look at this gist https://gist.github.com/Yayo-Arellano/b24b1d4e986c837303dc2b4e84281cac i just did on the fly it may have mistakes but the important is you get the idea.